# Make fonts larger in Galaxy Tab

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab

How can I enlarge all texts in galaxy tab for an old man, specially in contacts and more specially numbers of contacts?

Thank you.

*edit* galaxy tab version 2.2

Comment: Can you please post what version of Android your Galaxy Tab is running?  I don't know when the new 10.1 inch devices ship but they are supposed to run 3.0, while the older Galaxy Tab was running 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individual apps might have settings for font size, but I don't think Android 2.2 included any system-wide settings for changing the default font size.  Check the Market for a third-party contact list app that allows you to change that setting.

Comment: I'd suggest one but I'm a little swamped at work atm :)

Comment: anyone can suggest a tested contact management software for old men?

Answer (score 1):

Use [IDEAL Text Enlarger](http://apps4android.org/textenlarger/). Works without need for root. But not all apps work with it and overly large fonts make the interface more difficult.

I'm looking for a similar solution, but in terms of accessibility, the iPad's triple finger gesture to zoom and magnify any part of the screen in any app is unmatchable in Android as yet.

Comment: iPad doesn't make calls :)

Comment: Nope and neither does the iPad2